# Can you reset an ActiveRecord instance if its validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

Let's say you had a user with an age attribute that could not be negative

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
end
```

If you attempt to update attributes to a negative number validation will fail but the instance will still have a negative age value

```
#<User id: 1, age: 5, created_at: "2014-11-08 20:14:12", updated_at: "2014-11-08 20:14:12">
user.update_attributes!(:age => -5)
#<User id: 1, age: -5, created_at: "2014-11-08 20:14:12", updated_at: "2014-11-08 20:14:12">
```

Other than catching ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid and reseting the value yourself is their a way to reset an instance if its validations fail?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `model.reload` if the validation fails. So it will look something like:

```
if @model.update_attributes(age: params[:age]) # params[:age] = -5 for example
  # model is valid and saved, continue...
else # update_attributes return false and will not raise an exception if model is invalid
  # model is invalid, reloading...
  @model.reload
  # if we call @model.age now, it will return previous value
end
```

Anyway, update_attributes will set attributes even model is becoming invalid after that update, although it will not persist invalid attributes to database. But remember it will reset all other changes which may have been performed inside this call, so `update_attributes(name: params[:name], age: params[age])` will reset both name and age even name is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need a custom validator, e.g:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    unless record.age.to_i > 0
      record.errors[:name] << 'Invalid!'
      record.age = record.age_was # Rewrite new with old value
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

With `ActiveModel::Dirty` there's no need to reload.